# How to achieve this UI/UX design for an iOS UIButton object

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uibutton, uistoryboard

[image]

Look at the cool UI Trick for the "Forgot your login details? Get help signing in." button. How did they break the button into a clickable and non-clickable section? If it's not a single button but a label and a button, then, how did they get the second line of the button to be centred?

Comment: looks like web page

Comment: try [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) or [FRHyperLabel](https://github.com/null09264/FRHyperLabel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attributed string to set button title. See the code below for reference.

```
    func attributedText(){
            // create attributed string
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Don't have an account? ")
        let myString = "Sign Up"
        let myAttribute = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 194/255, green: 159/255, blue: 74/255, alpha: 1.0) ]
        let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttribute) 
        attributedString.append(myAttrString)    
        myCustomButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)

    }
```

Comment: But wouldn't it make the entire string a button instead of the words 'Sign up.'?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like that:

[image]

Here I am using two label and put a button on other label which i want to make clickable.

Comment: @Manan This is accepted answer but when user click on `ils?` from the word `details?` then button click event will be called. so maybe this is not right approach.

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani yes thats true. But we can do only one thing either make UI as it is. Or else make second line that contains "in" in little right hand side so it will not cover the "details". Is there any other way?

Comment: I have already commented libraries that are working as expected

Answer (score 1):

This is a label and a button without name above the blue colored text, so drag a label to your storyboard and connect it to your swift file(I named it labelText) and a button above the text you want.

Then inside your viewDidLoad function put this lines:

```
    // You can change the color as you want
    let color: UIColor = UIColor(red: 2/255.0, green: 202/255.0, blue: 246/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    let string_to_color = "Get help signing in."

    let titleStr: String = labelText.text!

    let range: NSRange = (titleStr as NSString).rangeOfString(string_to_color)

    let str: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleStr)
    str.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color, range: range)
    //Below line is if you want a line under your colored text
    //str.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: range)

    labelText.attributedText = str
```

And now you are set to go.

Happy coding.